# button click not working after view rotation android

Tags: android, animation, button, onclick, rotation

I have one relative layout, inside it i added three Image button dynamically.

when layout first appear all the three button action click event working properly, but i rotate whole layout as per sensor changed, after some rotation of layout all button's postion are changed but now i can't get click event of those buttons again at new postion instead i got click event on those button's previous positions.

please suggest me proper solution.

any help would be appreciated.

Below is code for how i added button and apply roation to it's parent view.

```
    ImageButton mImage = new ImageButton(context);      
    mImage.setX(x);
    mImage.setY(x);
    mImage.setId(id);
    mImage.setTag(id);
    mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
    this.addView(mImage);
```

rotation Code,

```
     RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree, -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    ra.setDuration(210);
    ra.setFillAfter(false);
    view.startAnimation(ra);
```

Comment: xml won't help very much if he adds the Buttons "dynamically" --> via Java. Please post your code

Comment: Did you get answer for same..?